# Update table, but make a new updated table?

Tags: sql

I am comparing two tables A and B. A and B are months (we will go with JAN and FEB).
FEB has updated data that belongs in JAN.

I need to update the data like so

```
UPDATE A
SET A.x = B.x, A.y = B.y, A.z = B.z
FROM JAN A, FEB B
WHERE (A.x <> B.x OR A.y <> B.y OR A.z <> B.z) AND A.PK = B.PK
```

Now I want the above to not take place on the Original JAN table.
Should I go about it this way? Or is there a better way?

```
SELECT *
INTO JAN_UPDATED
FROM JAN

UPDATE A
SET A.x = B.x, A.y = B.y, A.z = B.z
FROM JAN_UPDATED A, FEB B
WHERE (A.x <> B.x OR A.y <> B.y OR A.z <> B.z) AND A.PK = B.PK
```

EDIT: I want all of the original values + the updates in the new table

EDIT: Added PK

Comment: There should also be a key column or set of columns, so that you would know which `FEB` row to compare with which `JAN` row. As it is, you are actually comparing *any* row of `JAN` with *any* row of `FEB`, and I expect there could be (way too) many matches (rows that differ in at least one of the three columns).

Comment: That is, your condition should probably look like this: `WHERE A.key = B.key AND (A.x <> B.x OR ... )`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an outer join, you could select the data into a new table *and* update them along the way. Here's how:

```
SELECT    A.PK,
          COALESCE(B.x, A.x) AS x,
          COALESCE(B.y, A.y) AS x,
          COALESCE(B.z, A.z) AS x,
          other columns as necessary
INTO      JAN_UPDATED
FROM      JAN A
LEFT JOIN FEB B ON A.PK = B.PK AND (A.x <> B.x OR A.y <> B.y OR A.z <> B.z)
```

The left part of the join, the `JAN` table, will return all the `JAN` rows, and the right part of the join, `FEB`, will only return matching rows, those which are different from their counterparts in `JAN`. When there's no match, the right part's columns will be filled with `NULL`s. Now, when pulling values, the `COALESCE()` function is used for `x`, `y`, and `z`: the `FEB` version is tried first, and if it is `NULL` (meaning this is a non-matching `JAN` row, the one that has no updates in `FEB`), then the `JAN` party (the unchanged value) is used instead.

Answer (score 1):

The approach you are following is correct one if you require original records and updated one.

We cann't follow any other approach because there is no primary key defined on the tables.

Your solution also has fuzzy logic because it can update wrong records.

Comment: Will this copy over the entire table? As in a full replica of A plus the updates?

Comment: it will have only the updates in JAN_UPDATED. If you want the original values also then your solution is perfect.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Glad I got it right. In a sense I want to keep a backup of my original table. If you create a new answer I will mark it as correct.

Comment: How do the FEB values get put into JAN_UPDATED? or how do the JAN values get over written by the FEB values?